# Nuitka uses a special character “~” in temp

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, nuitka

Nuitka uses the `~` symbol when creating temporary files. example "Temp/ONEFIL~1/...". many components complain about this. need to find a way to remove the special character

I tried to find it on the Internet tried to read the documentation (but not so in depth)

mediapipe cannot find the directory when using such characters [image: error-photo]

Comment: Could you clarify why this is a problem / what you mean by "and many components complain about this"? `~` is an ordinary printable ASCII character and is allowed in filenames in most (all?) Unix and Windows filesystems. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

Comment: @Brian61354270. mediapipe cannot find the directory when using such characters. 
 [Photo-error](https://i.imgur.com/xY9NGX5.jpeg)

Comment: It could be that the underlying filesystem is FAT32/VFAT and the filename is in fact the shrot 8.3 name under the VFAT scheme (which is a completely valid file name), see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928982/what-is-the-difference-between-vfat-and-fat32-file-systems).

Comment: it turns out that I misunderstood the mistake, that's what helped me
'--include-package-data=mediapipe'